# Default value for Spring Data REST projection values?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have a Spring Data REST projection configured and it works as expected when the related data can be found. But when the related data is not found, it throws the following error:

```
{
"timestamp": 1532021102433,
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException",
"message": "Could not write JSON document: EL1007E: Property or field 'model' cannot be found on null (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources[\"_embedded\"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap[\"processed\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$ProjectionResource[\"content\"]->com.sun.proxy.$Proxy122[\"model\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: EL1007E: Property or field 'model' cannot be found on null (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources[\"_embedded\"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap[\"processed\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$ProjectionResource[\"content\"]->com.sun.proxy.$Proxy122[\"model\"])",
"path": "/processed/search/findByCompCode"
}
```

Here is what my Projection interface looks like:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.Projection;

import java.util.Date;

@Projection(name = "usage-detail", types = {Usage.class})
interface UsageProjection {
String getUuid();
String getProduct();
Date getReportDate();
String getVin();

@Value("#{target.vehicleInfo.make}")
String getMake();

@Value("#{target.vehicleInfo.model}")
String getModel();

@Value("#{target.vehicleInfo.modelYear}")
Integer getModelYear();
}
```

"vehicleInfo" is a field from the main Usage class which has a @ManyToOne join to another class called VehicleInfo which provides the make, model and modelYear data points. However, not every Usage record has matching vehicleInfo. When no match is found, the error is thrown.

I am looking for a way to provide default values for vehicleInfo. According to Spring documentation, I could do something like this:

```
@Value("#{target.vehicleInfo.make} ?: 'not available' ")
String getMake();
```

But that didn't work for me. :( I still get the same error as quoted above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is indicating that `vehicleInfo` itself is null, so you need to use the safe navigation operator.  Also, brackets need to be around the entire expression so that SpEL will evaluate the whole thing.

```
@Value(“#{target.vehicleInfo?.make ?: ‘not available’}“)
String getMake();
```

Comment: Thank you Becca!! That worked perfectly and really helped me out! :) I played with your solution and see that if I don't want a default value, but just want to avoid the error, I can simply do: 

    @Value("#{target.vehicleInfo?.make}")
    String getMake()